Printing long distance infrastructure
I am designing a long distance fibre optic network. At the end of my design period I need to do a print to PDF which only follows the route I designed. Because the route is not direct, when I do a print run, I end up with a lot of maps for areas that do not have any works to be completed. I believe that I would need to apply a map definition based on a single layer (say "fibre run"). I have looked through the plugins for printing and none of the definitions jump out as answering this need. The print process would need to reorient the pages to maximise coverage of the printed maps. The maps are then included in a Request for Quote so they need to be readable. I use an A1 size as the standard size basis.
I know that this capability exists in ArcGIS. Just hoping there is a way to do this in QGIS.

In QGIS, you can achieve the functionality you are looking for by using the Atlas feature along with map layouts. Here's a general outline of the steps you can take to accomplish this:

Create a layer that represents the route of the fibre optic network. This will serve as the coverage layer for the map extents.

Set up a map layout in QGIS and add a map element to represent the area covered by the fibre optic network.

Enable the Atlas feature in the map layout and set the coverage layer to be your fibre optic route layer. This will automatically generate maps based on the extent of the coverage layer.

Configure the map layout to reorient pages to maximize coverage of the printed maps. You can use the 'controlled by atlas' feature to adjust the map frame extent and rotation based on the coverage layer.

Use A1 size as the standard page size for your map layout.

Customize the map layout to ensure the maps are readable, including adding labels, legends, scale bars, etc.


By following these steps, you should be able to create a printout that follows the route you designed, and it will only show the relevant areas along the route, minimizing unnecessary maps for areas with no works to be completed. While QGIS may require a slightly different approach than ArcGIS, the Atlas feature provides the capability to achieve the desired outcome.
